# PHP downloading script

Tags: php, download, readfile

I'm trying to write a php script that will check parameters passed in before it initiates a download to the client. I've started by attempting to just initiate a download:

```
    <?php
    $file =  '/tticon.jpg';

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

When I navigate to this script it shows a blank page and nothing happens. How do I initiate a download?

Comment: have you tried removing the `flush()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `application/force-download` as Content-Type. If you want to show the image in the brwoser you can use `image/jpg`.

Comment: **Do not** change the content type to force a download.  This is poor practice, as the client then has no idea what kind of file it is.

Comment: He wants a `downloading script`; so it should be the best choice. But I suggested `image/jpg` as well.

Comment: The best choice is to set the content disposition.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
```

Comment: **Do not** change the content type to force a download.  This is poor practice, as the client then has no idea what kind of file it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file's extension is ".jpg" I assume it's mime is `image/jpeg`.

Replace this line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

with this:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

If you really want to force the browser to download the file (which I find very unlikely, anyway):

Replace the line with this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$file` looks suspect. Do you really have a tticon.jpg in the root directory of your server? Remember that PHP's file-functions operate on the FILESYSTEM of the server, not the WEB directories that Apache presents. PHP will not magically pre-pend your site's document root to that path. It's literally going to be looking in the root directory of the server's file system, NOT in the document root of your site.

Comment: How would I find where my file exists in relation to my server's root?

Comment: `find / -name tticon.jpg`, then check your webserver's config for the document root settings.